# interior of convex hull relatively open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Consider $k+1$ affinely independent vectors $\left\{p_0,p_1, \dots, p_k \right \}$ in $n$-dimensional euclidean vector space $n>k$ and consider their convex hull. It is known that each point $x$ of it can be written in form $x = \sum_{i=0}^k \lambda_ip_i, \sum_{i=0}^k \lambda_i = 1, \lambda_i \geq 0, 0 \leq i \leq k$. Interior of it is defined requiring for $\lambda_i, 0 \leq i \leq k$  to be **positive**. How could I prove that this *interior* is open in relative topology?

My try:

Pick $x = \sum_{i=0}^k \lambda_ip_i, \sum_{i=0}^k \lambda_i = 1, \lambda_i > 0, 0 \leq i \leq k$.

I want to find $\epsilon$ ball around it s.t. $\forall t\in B_\epsilon (x), t=\sum_{i=0}^k \mu_ip_i, \sum_{i=0}^k \mu_i = 1, \mu_i > 0, 0 \leq i \leq k $

We first perturbe $\lambda_0$: Take $\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{2}\min\left\{\lambda_0, 1-\lambda_0, 1-\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i\right\}>0$ (motivation for taking such is the fact $0<\lambda_0<1$)

Pick arbitrary $\mu_0$ in $[\lambda_0 - \epsilon_0,\lambda_0 + \epsilon_0]$. It is easy to show that in this case $0<\mu_i<1$ and $\mu_0+\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i <1$.

Idea is to continue this procedure taking $\epsilon_1 = \frac{1}{2}\min\left\{\lambda_1, 1-\lambda_1, 1-\sum_{i=2}^k \lambda_i - \mu_0 \right\}>0$. In this step I easily show that for $\mu_1$ in $[\lambda_1 - \epsilon_1,\lambda_1 + \epsilon_1]$ we have $0<\mu_1<1$, but struggle to prove $\mu_0 + \mu_1 + \sum_{i=2}^k \lambda_i < 1$.

If I eventually prove this and continue to go on like this (changing lambdas), I would then take my $\epsilon = \min_{i=0,...,k} \epsilon_i$ which in max-norm should fit to prove the desired fact.

Am I completely wrong? Does anyone have advice/more elegant idea? Since I don't have much theory developed, I have to go to find $\epsilon$-ball around $x$ with such properties, but didn't manage to find more sophisticated thing.

Comment: I'm not sure if the bounty comment "the current answers are out of date" is supposed to apply to Mandrathax's answer, but it seems correct to me. To state it differently, $p_0,\ldots,p_k$ have been assumed to be affinely independent, so in fact there is an affine isomorphism of their affine span taking the situation to the standard simplex on $\mathbb{R}^k$, for which the result is clear.

Comment: A more interesting situation is we drop the assumption that $p_0,\ldots,p_k$ are affinely independent: then if I am not mistaken, it is still true that their convex-hull-with-positive-coefficients is relatively open in their affine span, but this time we need to appeal to Carathéodory's theorem so see it.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, bounty expires in a day or two. I also think it should be fine, but a tiny thing still bothers me . Anyways, feel free to post your remark as a comment. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull) 
Can it happen that $Int (P) \subset P'$ to ruin everything?... Or in this case we can apply theorem again and again until $P^{\left(k\right)}\subset Int (P)$, where the theorem is applied $k$ times, $k>1$. I cannot see it rigourously.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathrm{Int}(P)$ and $P'$ in your last comment? I imagine $\mathrm{Int}(P)$ is the interior convex hull (which you really should have called something else, like "strict-convex-hull", because it's more or less the whole point whether it is, indeed, the topological interior), but what's $P'$?

Comment: The argument is really simple: (A) we can assume w.l.o.g. that $n=k$ and that $p_0,\ldots,p_k$ span the affine space in which they live, by restricting to their span, (B) in case $p_0,\ldots,p_k$ are the standard simplex, the statement is true because the strict-convex-hull is an intersection of open hyperplanes, and (C) by an affine isomorphism we can reduce to case (B).  Which part is unclear?

Comment: For the first... I use the notation from wiki-page on Caratheodory's theorem, from the link in the comment.
For the second, problem is actually from simplex theory... I want to prove that open simplex is (simplex with all $\lambda$s positive) is topologically open. I think that it is now OK. The thing was that I didn't know how to argument that $f$ in his solution indeed maps onto $C$. $\lambda$s in the definition of $H$ can be arbitrary reals and those in the domain of $f$ are positive, so this follows by definition, right?

Comment: First, just to clarify, my remark about Carathéodory's theorem was destined to solve a more general question than the one you asked, namely without the assumption that $p_0,\ldots,p_k$ are affinely independent. If you're not interested in this more general situation, ignore Carathéodory. If you are, it's probably best to make a different question of this. • Second, yes, in Mandrathax's answer, the $\lambda$ in the definition of $H$ are arbitrary (whereas in $f$ they are positive, as indicated in the source of $f$).

Comment: So $f(R_+^{*^{k+1}})=\mathring C$ was meant to be $f(H\cap R_+^{*^{k+1}}) = \mathring C$, right? 

Thanks for your collaboration and interest.

Comment: Indeed, it should be $f(H\cap (\mathbb{R}_+^*)^{k+1})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK let $C$ be your convex hull, $H=\{\lambda\in\mathbb R^{k+1}\vert \sum_i\lambda_i=1\}$ (affine subspace of $\mathbb R^{k+1}$). Let $f:H\cap\mathbb R_+^{k+1}\longrightarrow C$ such that $f(\lambda)=\sum_i\lambda_ip_i$. Notice that $f$ is continuous.

Now since the $p_i$ are affinely independent, you can calculate $f^{-1}$ by solving a linear system. Since solving a linear system only involves continuous operations, $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Hence $f$ is a homeomorphism.

This means that $f(R_+^{*^{k+1}})=\mathring C$ is open in $C$ since $R_+^{*^{k+1}}$ is open in $R_+^{k+1}$.

Qed

Comment: May I ask you to write down what exactly $H$ is, because I cannot see how $\lambda$ and these $\lambda_i$-s relate from your notation. However, thank you for your interest.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I used the implicit notation $\lambda=(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_{k+1})$, it's often used for vectors.